# webpack-dev-middleware and Express - can't get them to collaborate

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

I am trying to set up my first project using Webpack and Express but somehow I am doing something wrong.

This is what I did:

**1. CREATED SAMPLE PROJECT**
Created a sample project using `express-generator`. My folder structure is something like:

```
express-project
  -app.js
  -webpack.config.js
  -public
    -javascripts
      -modules
      -build
```

**2. SET UP HANDLEBARS**
Set up `handlebars` as view/template engine and created a couple of routes

**3. WEBPACK CODE**
Created the Webpack specific code/configuration as follows

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var webpackHotMiddleware = 'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=2000&overlay=false';

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            handlebars: path.resolve('public/vendor/handlebars-v4.0.5.js'),
            bootstrap: path.resolve('public/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js'),
            pubsub: path.resolve('public/vendor/ba-tiny-pubsub.js')
        }
    },
    context: path.resolve('public/javascripts'),
    entry: {
        cart: ['./modules/cart', webpackHotMiddleware],
        index: ['./modules/products.js', webpackHotMiddleware],
        vendor: ['bootstrap', 'pubsub', webpackHotMiddleware]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('public/javascripts/build'),
        publicPath: 'javascripts/build/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: "[id].js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            // some loaders here
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ]
}
```

**app.js**

```
// some code before
var app = express();
(function() {

  // Step 1: Create & configure a webpack compiler
  var webpack = require('webpack');
  var webpackConfig = require(process.env.WEBPACK_CONFIG ? process.env.WEBPACK_CONFIG : './webpack.config');
  var compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

  // Step 2: Attach the dev middleware to the compiler & the server
  app.use(require("webpack-dev-middleware")(compiler, {
    noInfo: false,
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    stats: {
      colors: true
    }
  }));

  // Step 3: Attach the hot middleware to the compiler & the server
  app.use(require("webpack-hot-middleware")(compiler, {
    log: console.log,
    path: '/__webpack_hmr',
    heartbeat: 10 * 1000
  }));
})();
// some code after
```

**4. JS CODE ON TEMPLATE**
Then on the handlebars page I require the bundled javascripts

```
<script src="javascripts/build/common.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/build/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/build/cart.js"></script>
```

**5. NPM START**
Finally if I start the server using the *standard* `npm start` I see in the shell that webpack bundles everything with no errors but if I go to `localhost:3000/` it does not find any of the assets created by Webpack. Instead if I run `webpack` to create the various bundles as if I were on production, everything is created correctly and it works as expected.

Hope someone can figure out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out what was causing the problem, by adding a slash in these 2 lines everything started to work properly:

```
context: path.resolve('public/javascripts/'),
path: path.resolve('public/javascripts/build/'),
```